# What news aggregator with approval system can I use?

Tags: rss

We have an automated news feed that publishes news articles on our website when we have been mentioned in the media, but before the articles are published we would like to approve (or reject) them.

The dirtiest way to do it is to use a Google News RSS feed, and then when an article is published we post a link in our "news" section of the site, but this is too manual.

What we would like to do - and I think Yahoo pipes is the technology we need to use - is to have the ability to 'approve' or 'reject' a news article and then the approved articles will be fed through to the widget that will be published on our website.

Will yahoo pipes let us do this? or am I stretching the functionality out a bit?

Comment: Is there any particular CMS/framework managing the site? That would give more context for recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it -

- Subscribe to the automated Feed through Google Reader.
- You can [Delicious](http://delicious.com) for approving specific feed items. [Add Delicious as a service to which you want to send the feed items to](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/08/google-readers-send-to-feature.html)
- While you read each feed, select "Send to" and choose Delicious to save the items of interest to [Delicious](http://delicious.com)
- On Delicious, you can get a public feed for only the links you've "bookmarked" with the option of including the complete or a summary of the feed description
- Use your public Delicious feed to display curated content on your company's website

Note that Delicious may not immediately update your feed as you Send posts from Google Reader to Delicious and this process has a dependency on the availability of Delicious

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the need for Yahoo Pipes and save yourself a step by grabbing the feed from Google reader itself. You can create a public feed from "Starred" items in Google reader then use that feed to auto post to your site.

I believe you can further break it down if you use tags IE auto post to, say wordpress, the starred feed from Google reader, and add each item to it's own category based on the tag you designated in Google reader.

All Yahoo pipes does is allow you to manipulate the feed to generate a new feed, so assuming all you need is a list approved items, and their category you won't get any benefit from using pipes (although it should be able to accomplish the same task).

Comment: I think that used to be possible, but now you cannot (at least natively) make a public feed from any of your Google Reader feeds.

Comment: It does appear things have changed a bit since I last tried it, however, I still think it's possible via the "Send to" feature, if not out of the box then some combo of "bundles" or the export feature should make this possible.

Comment: It had me puzzled because I was following your instructions and then hit a wall when I realised that the feed was not public. I went with mvark's solution below and it works quite well.